# How to post data on facebook wall with regular editText and button

Tags: android, facebook

By facebook default message post

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void postToWall() {
    // post on user's wall.
    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });

}
```

we can share data but want to do the same thing with regular edit text and button,Is there any way to do this,please suggest me,thanku

Answer (score 0):

this will help you.

```
 Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
 parameters.putString("message", "Test");
 parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
 facebook.request("me");
 facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
```

Comment: this wont help surely